# Вывод и редактирование новости php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Нашел простой гайд как сделать админпанель с возможностью постинга и редактирования постов.
Сделал всё как в видео, но добавление и редактирование новостей не работает
Работает только логин и регистрация.

PHP не знаю совсем, только HTML+CSS+JS

Прошу помочь с функционалом добавления и редактирования новостей.

https://yadi.sk/d/ZDKQ_VpTn7marg
http://t99915ab.beget.tech/

Comment: github - нет, не слышали

Comment: Github позволяет выводить только статику

Comment: код в студию. по сторонним ресурсам тут никто лазить не будет и самостоятельно разбираться где там у вас и что. Конкретные блоки кода, где что-то не работает приложите к вопросы. Если собираетесь что-то делать на пхп, потрудитесь сначала прочитать документацию. ее там не так уж и много.

Comment: Небольшое отступление от основного вопроса. Поправка:
Нет необходимости использовать сложнейшую библиотеку jQuery для скрытия или отображения элементов. Ваш сайт не настолько большой, чтобы использовать такого рода продукты.
А по самому вопросу:
Необходим код ошибки или исходный код для успешной диагностики ошибки.